# Retrieve an element of a list associated to an other element

Tags: python, list, dictionary, element

Here is my list :

```
List1 = [['movies', 0.0], ['minion 2015', 1.0], ['minion 2016', 0.3333333333333333]]
```

I would like to recover the element associated to the value "1.0" who is "minion 2015". It's possible to do that?

---

Some details :

My example is due to a return of a value I got from my script.
This result first shows me a list like list 'list1'. 
Then a processing of this list with a condition returns the result item `[1.0]`. 
And I would like to know if we can retrieve the element associated with this element (1.0) which is `"minion 2015"`in output.

Comment: How do mean recover? It was never lost.

Comment: What do you mean by recover?

Comment: is it sure that the value is unique?

Comment: Hum, retrieve what i meant

Comment: @Taylor08 take a look at the example I gave below using `filter` function.

Comment: I would just do `[sublist[0] for sublist in List1 if sublist[1] == 1.0][0]`.

Comment: @StamKaly or `next(k for k,v in list1 if v == 1.0)`... You could also then provide a default parameter for where no match is found instead of a `StopIteration` being raised...

Comment: @JonClements I've created a generic version of this using `yield from` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It can be done.

I would recommend you to read this [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) like below:

```
filtered_list = list(filter(lambda i: i[1] == 1.0, my_list))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> my_list = [['movies', 0.0], ['minion 2015', 1.0], ['minion 2016', 0.3333333333333333]]
>>> filtered_list = list(filter(lambda i: i[1] == 1.0, my_list))
>>> filtered_list
[['minion 2015', 1.0]]
>>> filtered_list[0][0]
'minion 2015'
```